# Where are Time Machine local snapshots stored in High Sierra

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra

Apple says that this space is hidden and not accessible to users, but I don't think it's like that. It must be stored some where, so where could this be stored?

Comment: What are you trying to do? In High Sierra local snapshots are created more often than previously. Have a look at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015. Use TimeMachine to remove local snapshots so you don't shoot yourself in the foot with a bazooka.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81171

Answer (score 1):

Local snapshots are stored in `/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots`

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81171

Comment: I am on MacOS Mojave and I don't see the /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots folder in /Volumes (even as root in Terminal) so I think this has been changed in Mojave.

Comment: @Turribeach With APFS snapshots, you have to mount the desired snapshot yourself: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/347257

Comment: I'm on High Sierra, I don't see this directory, but `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` lists them. Is it because my boot disk is APFS?

Answer (score 1):

To display /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots in Finder in High Sierra or Mojave do the following:

• Hold the Command+Shift buttons then press on the . (dot) button

• This will enable the option to view hidden files

• Hold the Command button and press Space

• This will open the Spotlight search window

• Type /Volumes and press Enter

[To turn off viewing hidden files do Command + Shift + . (dot) a second time.]