# Some files disappear from an APFS snapshot

Tags: backup, filesystem, apfs

I'm using rsync on top of a [mount_apfs snapshots](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/347257/238365), to backup a consistent file system view and without having to stop applications during the backup.

While so far, it has been working pretty well, from time to time rsync shows messages like:

```bsh
mount_apfs: snapshot implicitly mounted readonly
file has vanished: "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/leveldb/021794.ldb"
file has vanished: "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/leveldb/021795.ldb"
file has vanished: "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/leveldb/021796.ldb"
rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at main.c(1209) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Which usually happens when an application interferes with rsync by deleting files in the middle of a backup.

To me, a snapshot is supposed to offer a frozen view of the file system at some point, but maybe it's not exactly like that for an Apple snapshot?

Comment: The path shown isn't from a snapshot, though? Snapshots will still mount like a regular volume in `/Volumes` - the path here is in your root working disk.

Comment: Thanks @EzekielElin, I got inspiration from your answer (see below), but the problem is different. rsync lists those paths referring to its source parameter, using /Volumes is just a convention, a filesys can be mounted anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the way tmutil works for snapshots, I've created a [different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409439/tmutil-doesnt-create-a-real-snapshot-since-catalina) about it.